# Using the 'send' action without saving first causes a warning about data loss. How can I turn this warning off?

Tags: orbeon

When using the 'send' action without using the save action first the user is warned "You may lose some unsaved changes." How can I turn this warning off?

Example process and button:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.*.*">
    send(
              uri="http://localhost:80/myservice",
              content="xml",
              replace="none"
             )
    then success-message(message="Save Successful")
    recover error-message(message="Save Failed")
</property>

<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*">
    send-to-myservice
</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set-data-status(status="safe")`. Example below. [Docs are here](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#set-data-status).

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.*.*">
    set-data-status(status="safe")
    then send(
              uri="http://localhost:80/myservice",
              content="xml",
              replace="none"
             )
    then success-message(message="Save Successful")
    recover error-message(message="Save Failed")
</property>

<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*">
    send-to-myservice
</property>
```